# Mysql connection taking too much time

Tags: mysql, database

I am using mysql 5.5.32. Below is my configuration file (my.cnf)...

```
[mysqld]
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
# Disabling symbolic-links is recommended to prevent assorted security risks
symbolic-links=0
# Settings user and group are ignored when systemd is used.
# If you need to run mysqld under a different user or group,
# customize your systemd unit file for mysqld according to the
# instructions in http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Systemd

innodb_file_per_table=1
skip-name-resolve
innodb_data_file_path = ibdata1:2000M;ibdata2:10M:autoextend

log-error=/var/log/mysql/mysql_error.log
long_query_time=1
slow_query_log=1
log-warnings=2
slow-query-log-file=/var/log/mysql/log-slow-queries.log

#starting
#old_passwords=1

#log-bin
#binlog-do-db=<database name>  # input the database which should be replicated
#binlog-ignore-db=mysql            # input the database that should be ignored for replication
#binlog-ignore-db=test


server-id=1
#ending

open_files_limit= 2000
thread_cache_size = 64

query_cache_limit=400M
query_cache_size = 400M
query_cache_type=1
[mysql.server]
user=mysql
basedir=/var/lib

[mysqld_safe]
#log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
```

when I restart mysql then i entered into mysql console very quickly. After some time when I try to enter into mysql console then it takes around 15-20 seconds.

I used the command **show processlist** to check the queries, but no load on mysql server.

why it is taking too much time ? How to track what is the error ?

Comment: The logs don't show anything?, it's really strange, i don't see anything strange with your configuration file....

Comment: Log showing nothing...

Answer (score 0):

Use this sentence `log-slow-queries=/var/log/mysql/log-slow-queries.log` instead of `slow-query-log-file=/var/log/mysql/log-slow-queries.log` i think this is the problem you are not seeing anything in log file

Ensure you have the file

```
touch /var/log/mysql/log-slow-queries.log
chown mysql.mysql -R /var/log/mysql
```

I get this ideas from here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/slow-query-log.html, so take a look to see something useful

Comment: Did you restart your database after changes right?. I don't know what's happening... still thinking. I have similar problem months ago and the problem was a cron  script that check so many things using database.... but if you don't see anything with `show processlist` i don't know....

Comment: there is no any issue in mysql from last 1 hour...I added this in my.cnf sort_buffer_size = 8M,
read_buffer_size = 8M,
read_rnd_buffer_size = 8M,
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 200M,join_buffer_size=400M,